# Sending appended jQuery content to ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, append

I'm working on something like a static basket and trying to create jQuery function that I can use every time the "Add" button is clicked that append another container with these HTML tags (div, header, list). **[The function is worked fine statically](http://jsfiddle.net/Lx7CC/1/).**

I need to send these appended content to asp.net (VB) when click save button without I a PostBack with every jquery add step .. **is it possible**?  . I have a working ASP.NET function that sends the static DIV content through ASP.NET correctly to the database but it couldn't send the appended java-script content.

## Markup

```
<div class="grid">
    <h1>ITEMS TO ADD</h1>
    <div class="row" id="fruits">
       <h2><a href="">Fruits</a></h2>
       <a class="AddItem" href="javascript:void(0)">+</a>
       <div class="item" id="1" rel="apple">
          <label for="apple">APPLE</label>
          <div class="helper">
             <input name="my-input" size="1" type="text" value="0" />
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="appender" id="basket" runat="server">
</div>
```

## VB.NET

```
Private Function GetHtmlData(ByVal HTML As HtmlGenericControl) As String

    Dim SB As New StringBuilder()
    Dim SW As New StringWriter(SB)
    Dim HTW As New HtmlTextWriter(SW)
    HTML.RenderControl(HTW)
    Return SB.ToString()

End Function
'''' // And I call the function in part of my code with:
objDb.cmdUpdate.Parameters("@Data").Value = GetHtmlData(basket)
```

## jQuery

```
var _rows, _list, _menu, _item, _number;
$.each($('.AddItem'), function () {
    $(this).click(function () {
        _id = $(this).parent().attr("id");
        _menu = $(this).parent().find("h2 a").text();
        _item = $(this).parent().find(".item");
        AddNewItem(_menu)

        $(_item).each(function () {
            _text = $(this).find("label").text();
            _number = $(this).find(".helper input[type=text]").val();
            AddElements(_text, _number);
        });

        //AddElements(_item)
    });

});
function AddNewItem(_menu) {
    _rows = $('#<%= basket.ClientID %>');
    _rows.append("<h2>" + _menu + "</h2>");
    _list = $("<ul>");
    _list.appendTo(_rows)
};
function AddElements(_text, _number) {
    _rows = $('#<%= basket.ClientID %>');
    var _li = $('<li>')
    _li.html('<span class="marker">' + _number + ' </span>' + ' <span class="item">' + _text + '</span>').appendTo(_list)

};
```

Comment: In general, you would use jQuery's `$.ajax()` function to send the data to the server, and on the server you would have a handler (or a page, though a handler is preferred) which receives the data and performs the server-side processing.  So every time a new element is added to the page, you can subsequently send the data to the server.  (And likely return a message indicating success, so if the server-side code fails then the client-side code can respond by removing the element and notifying the user of the error, so the elements don't get out of sync between the client and the server.)

Comment: Changes made client-side aren't reflected server-side. The way I've solved this in the past is to serialize the data client-side (to json, perhaps), and then put that in a hidden field or use ajax to send it to the server.

Comment: Thanks David, I couldn't get enough knowledge about using ajax and delaying it in all my modules for 2 years now and can't get where I should start. is there a way to this idea to work without or any good example/reference that close to mine :)